# Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1

Tags: testng-eclipse

I am trying to run a TestNG test using Jenkins. It's giving me configuration failure and skips. I have read similar questions here and in other website as well but they are not helpful. 
I have read this [enter link description here](http://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/testNG+Configuration+Failures%2C+Policy%2C+and+alwaysRun) and tried alwaysRun = true but even this does not solve my issue.

I am getting error like this:

Total tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 2
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1

My test is like below:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Search {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")

    public void crossBrowsers(String browser) throws InterruptedException {

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        }

        else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\mypath\\chromedriver.exe");

            driver = new ChromeDriver();

        }

        driver.navigate().to("myaddress");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

@Test
    public void methodA() throws InterruptedException {
}

@Test
    public void methodB() throws InterruptedException {
}

@AfterTest
    public void quitBrowsers() {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Stack trace of Publish TestNG Results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testng-results skipped="3" failed="0" total="6" passed="3">
  <reporter-output>
  </reporter-output>
  <suite name="Suite" duration-ms="28498" started-at="2017-12-07T09:51:27Z" finished-at="2017-12-07T09:51:55Z">
    <groups>
    </groups>
    <test name="FirefoxTest" duration-ms="11724" started-at="2017-12-07T09:51:27Z" finished-at="2017-12-07T09:51:38Z">
      <class name="scripts.CloseEachError">
        <test-method status="FAIL" signature="crossBrowsers(java.lang.String)[pri:0, instance:scripts.CloseEachError@1ff8b8f]" name="crossBrowsers" is-config="true" duration-ms="0" started-at="2017-12-07T10:51:27Z" finished-at="2017-12-07T10:51:27Z">
          <params>
            <param index="0">
              <value>
                <![CDATA[Firefox]]>
              </value>
            </param>
          </params>
          <exception class="org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException">
            <message>
              <![CDATA[Process unexpectedly closed with status: 0
Build info: version: '3.7.0', revision: '2321c73', time: '2017-11-02T22:12:07.291Z'
System info: host: 'BC_LT35', ip: '192.168.26.71', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   0:           0x47e934 - <no info>
   1:           0x47f0a3 - <no info>
   2:           0x442649 - <no info>
   3:           0x449cc3 - <no info>
   4:           0x42a890 - <no info>
   5:           0x406f5e - <no info>
   6:           0x40cfc9 - <no info>
   7:           0x6bef19 - <no info>
   8:           0x420756 - <no info>
   9:           0x6b96e0 - <no info>
  10:     0x7ffdf4d01fe4 - BaseThreadInitThunk]]>
            </message>
            <full-stacktrace>
              <![CDATA[org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 0
Build info: version: '3.7.0', revision: '2321c73', time: '2017-11-02T22:12:07.291Z'
System info: host: 'BC_LT35', ip: '192.168.26.71', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   0:           0x47e934 - <no info>
   1:           0x47f0a3 - <no info>
   2:           0x442649 - <no info>
   3:           0x449cc3 - <no info>
   4:           0x42a890 - <no info>
   5:           0x406f5e - <no info>
   6:           0x40cfc9 - <no info>
   7:           0x6bef19 - <no info>
   8:           0x420756 - <no info>
   9:           0x6b96e0 - <no info>
  10:     0x7ffdf4d01fe4 - BaseThreadInitThunk
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
    at scripts.CloseEachError.crossBrowsers(CloseEachError.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:616)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1355)
    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1324)
]]>
            </full-stacktrace>
          </exception> <!-- org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException -->
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- crossBrowsers -->
        <test-method status="SKIP" signature="clkDropDownBtn()[pri:0, instance:scripts.CloseEachError@1ff8b8f]" name="clkDropDownBtn" duration-ms="0" started-at="2017-12-07T10:51:38Z" finished-at="2017-12-07T10:51:38Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- clkDropDownBtn -->
        <test-method status="SKIP" signature="closeEachErr()[pri:0, instance:scripts.CloseEachError@1ff8b8f]" name="closeEachErr" duration-ms="0" started-at="2017-12-07T10:51:38Z" finished-at="2017-12-07T10:51:38Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- closeEachErr -->
        <test-method status="SKIP" signature="VerifyErrList()[pri:0, instance:scripts.CloseEachError@1ff8b8f]" name="VerifyErrList" duration-ms="0" started-at="2017-12-07T10:51:38Z" finished-at="2017-12-07T10:51:38Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- VerifyErrList -->
        <test-method status="SKIP" signature="quitBrowsers()[pri:0, instance:scripts.CloseEachError@1ff8b8f]" name="quitBrowsers" is-config="true" duration-ms="0" started-at="2017-12-07T10:51:38Z" finished-at="2017-12-07T10:51:38Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- quitBrowsers -->
      </class> <!-- scripts.CloseEachError -->
    </test> <!-- FirefoxTest -->
    <test name="ChromeTest" duration-ms="16743" started-at="2017-12-07T09:51:38Z" finished-at="2017-12-07T09:51:55Z">
      <class name="scripts.CloseEachError">
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="crossBrowsers(java.lang.String)[pri:0, instance:scripts.CloseEachError@5474c6c]" name="crossBrowsers" is-config="true" duration-ms="3587" started-at="2017-12-07T10:51:38Z" finished-at="2017-12-07T10:51:42Z">
          <params>
            <param index="0">
              <value>
                <![CDATA[Chrome]]>
              </value>
            </param>
          </params>
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- crossBrowsers -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="VerifyErrList()[pri:0, instance:scripts.CloseEachError@5474c6c]" name="VerifyErrList" duration-ms="41" started-at="2017-12-07T10:51:42Z" finished-at="2017-12-07T10:51:42Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- VerifyErrList -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="clkDropDownBtn()[pri:0, instance:scripts.CloseEachError@5474c6c]" name="clkDropDownBtn" duration-ms="12242" started-at="2017-12-07T10:51:42Z" finished-at="2017-12-07T10:51:54Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- clkDropDownBtn -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="closeEachErr()[pri:0, instance:scripts.CloseEachError@5474c6c]" name="closeEachErr" duration-ms="295" started-at="2017-12-07T10:51:54Z" finished-at="2017-12-07T10:51:54Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- closeEachErr -->
        <test-method status="PASS" signature="quitBrowsers()[pri:0, instance:scripts.CloseEachError@5474c6c]" name="quitBrowsers" is-config="true" duration-ms="577" started-at="2017-12-07T10:51:54Z" finished-at="2017-12-07T10:51:55Z">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- quitBrowsers -->
      </class> <!-- scripts.CloseEachError -->
    </test> <!-- ChromeTest -->
  </suite> <!-- Suite -->
</testng-results>
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">

   <test name="FirefoxTest">
  <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="scripts.testJenkins"/>
    </classes>
  </test>  <!-- SearchTest -->

       <test name="ChromeTest">
  <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="scripts.testJenkins"/>
    </classes>
  </test>  


</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: What is the command you are using on Jenkins ? Also attach the error stacktrace

Comment: I am giving bat file name in Execute Windows Batch Command.

Comment: I am adding stack trace using publish TestNG Results

Comment: **org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 0** what version of selenium are you using with firefox driver?

Comment: This is my version selenium-java-3.7.0

Comment: Firefox is 57.0 (64-bit)

Comment: test with FF 58.0b7 (64-bit) OR Firefox Nightly 59.0a1 (2017-11-30) (64-bit)
with *options.addPreference("security.sandbox.content.level", 5)*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160704/discussion-between-sarabu-sandeep-and-manmohan-singh).

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled my jenkins and installed again with war then it worked well.